# How to deploy Windows Service projects with Team Build 2010

Tags: .net, deployment, msbuild, windows-services, tfsbuild

I have a VS2010 solution, which includes several Windows Service projects. I need to deploy these services as part of a build in Team Build 2010, and the Windows Services have to be deployed on several Windows Server machines.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could **conditionally invoke the [SC.exe](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490995.aspx) command from your Windows Service project file** (*.csproj) to install the Windows Service on a remote machine.

Here's an example:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <DeployWinService>false</DeployWinService>
  <WinServiceName>MyService</WinServiceName>
  <TargetWinServiceHost Condition="'$(TargetWinServiceHost)' == ''">localhost</TargetWinServiceHost>
</PropertyGroup>

<Target Name="AfterCompile">
  <CallTarget Targets="PublishWinService" />
</Target>

<Target Name="PublishWinService"
        Condition="'$(DeployWinService)' == 'true'">
  <Exec Command="sc stop $(WinServiceName)" ContinueOnError="true" />
  <Exec Command="sc \\$(TargetWinServiceHost) create $(WinServiceName) binpath= '$(OutDir)\$(AssemblyName).exe' start= auto" />
</Target>
```

Here we are defining the custom MSBuild properties `DeployWinService` and `TargetWinServiceHost` that are used to control whether the output of the Windows Service project will be installed after compilation and to which machine. The `WinServiceName` property simply specifies the name that the Windows Service will have on the target machine.

In your **build definition** you'll have to explicitly set the `DeployWinService` and `TargetWinServiceHost` properties in the **MSBuild Arguments** field of the **Advanced** section:

```
/p:DeployWinService=true;TargetWinServiceHost=MACHINENAME
```

**Related resources:**

- [How to create a Windows service by using Sc.exe](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/251192)
- [Common MSBuild Project Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb629394.aspx)