# Install windows service as part of team build

Tags: service, installation, build-automation, tfsbuild

Followed the guidance [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5788648/how-to-deploy-windows-service-projects-with-team-build-2010/5789064#5789064) to publish my windows service successfully in tfs2010. But have a few more questions:

How could I modify this to install the service from the drop location instead of OutDir?
How could I make this install happen only after a successful build AND test is run?

Comment: Found it much cleaner to use the new Team Build Workflow insead of MSBuild. Added a sequence of "InvokeProcess"es to stop, delete, reinstall and start the windows service on each build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters, read [Fail a build if tests fail](http://blog.hinshelwood.com/fail-a-build-if-tests-fail/) to fail your build when your test fails. Then add a condition in your deploy action to make sure it is **only** activated when your build succeeds:

```
<Target Name="PublishWinService" 
    Condition="'$(DeployWinService)' == 'true'"
    Condition="'$(CompilationStatus)' == 'Succeeded'">
```

To install from your drop location instead of your build location, replace `$(OutDir)` by `$(DropLocation)` in the original post you are following.

That's all folks!