# How to deploy Windows Service with web site in Team Build?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, service, tfs, build

I have project in VS2012. which is build with  website and windows service application. i can easily able to deploy website on Remote machine but when i am trying to deploy windows service method ([How to deploy Windows Service projects with Team Build 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5788648/how-to-deploy-windows-service-projects-with-team-build-2010)), i am receiving this error. can any one please help out what special rights we have to apply?

The command "sc \x.y.z create MyService binpath= '\MyService.exe' start= auto" exited with code 5. Please verify that you have sufficient rights to run this command."

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does the build service account have Read/Write access to all folders specified, including being able to run sc.exe?

Comment: hey i am new to TFS, learning steps by step. i dont know how to verify if account has sc.exe run access? can you please guide me?

Comment: If you're doing this for a corporation, your best bet is to get your network support involved and tell them to verify the things I mentioned, it's something that takes a while to explain, and a network support person would be able to delve deeper.